# Stuck with stock rom

Tags: custom-roms, twrp, system

I have a galaxy s5 g900f and here is my problem i can't flash any custom rom i tried twrp cwm philz edition and the problem is the same i get stuck at* patching system image unconditionally at the very beginning of the blue line i tried with resurrection remix, slimrom, and other ROMs and when trying MIUI 8 i get an error couldn't mount system rw 
Itried with adb sideload get stucked at 45%. 
I e2fsck -y /dev/block/mmcblk0p23 wich is my system partition and fixed so many error but the problem stay the same ... i can flash a recovery or a kernel with no problem with TWRP the problem as i think when dealing with the system partition .. so im stuck with a stock rom that i flashed with odin btw who works great .. so is it my system partition messed up or the gpt table isnt right or is there a way to flash custom rom using odin

Comment: Stock ROM version (before you try doing any of this)? TWRP version? Potential mismatch factors here...

Comment: Rom 6.0.1 and i tried twrp 3.1.0.0 and 3.1.0.1

Comment: That seems fine, have no idea why it's happening.

Comment: I was thinking that the system partition is too small but it's about 1.5 Gb and the slimROm is barely 500 Gb

Comment: 500 Gb is really greater than 1.5

Comment: Sorry i mean Mb